# How to bevel edges together (from diferent objects)

Tags: bevel

It possible to bevel separate edges (even from separate objects) together? Without joining the edges (and preferably without joining the objects)? I have three separate planes, aligned together, and I want to give a curve to their end like in the top picture. (Sorry about the beautiful handwriting!)

[image: What I want to achieve]

[image: 3 separate planes]

Comment: I don't see how you could do it, you probably have a very easy way to do what you want, you could use the Knife Project Tool for example, but maybe tell a bit more about the whole object?

Comment: Actually these are parts of a sidewalk; the materials of the left and right planes are stone pavement/rubble and the middle one is grass. I would like the end of the sidewalk to have a curve -without mixing the materials. I have a solidify modifier, and a concrete border will enclose them later, but I think this is not relevant. I could join these with a circle or something, but I wanted to learn if it is at all possible to bevel separate edges together

Comment: I can't think of something like that but as I say, with the Knife Project tool you could project a shape of half circle then cut off the mesh

Comment: I don't think this is possible, at least certainly not with the _Bevel_ tool. You see, even if it was one object, the bevel would stop at the edges between the three parts or create some very bad overlapping.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion; I have been meaning vertices, not edges (as these are planes).
Btw, is there maybe some solution related to (the opposite of) `to sphere` tool or something like that?

Comment: Even vertices would be a problem already if it is all one object. The curvature itself consists of a few vertices I guess, so beveling the vertex at the corner will stop at the next vertex down the curve. You could then only make a small bevel, not the one you've drawn in there.